# How to take the first part of string before a specific string occurrence in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string that is -

```
<span style=\"font-weight: 800\">Residence, Effective Date: NA</span> <br />6367 US HIGHWAY 70 EAST<br />LA GRANGE NC 28551 <br />
```

I want to take the first part of the string before the first occurrence of `<br />` and that selected part should be like-

```
<span style=\"font-weight: 800\">Residence, Effective Date: NA</span>
```

currently I'm doing like-

```
string dictVal = "<span style=\"font-weight: 800\">Residence, Effective Date: NA</span> <br />6367 US HIGHWAY 70 EAST<br />LA GRANGE NC 28551 <br />";

                string[] items = dictVal.Split(new char[] { '<' },
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string firstPart = string.Join("<", items.Take(3));
```

but it's not working.

Comment: What is not working about it? Can you describe the behaviour you're seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`string.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) and [`string.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8):

```
string firstPart = dictVal.Substring(0, dictVal.IndexOf("<br />"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to take the first part you can use [Regex.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netframework-4.8) in the following way:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string dictVal= "< span style =\"font-weight: 800\">Residence, Effective Date: NA</span> <br />6367 US HIGHWAY 70 EAST<br />LA GRANGE NC 28551 <br />";
string first_value = Regex.Split(mystring, "<br />")[0]; //The 0 gets the first portion of the array, in this case it is the desired value

// And if you want to remove any spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string
string trim = first_value.Trim();
```